# Find max value within a data frame interval

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe that has x/y values every 5 seconds, with a depth value every second (time column). There is no depth where there is an x/y value.

```
x <- c("1430934", NA, NA, NA, NA, "1430939")
y <- c("4943206", NA, NA, NA, NA, "4943210")
time <- c(1:6)
depth <- c(NA, 10, 19, 84, 65, NA)
data <- data.frame(x, y, time, depth)
data 
     x       y      time depth
1 1430934 4943206    1    NA     
2    NA    NA        2    10     
3    NA    NA        3    19     
4    NA    NA        4    84     
5    NA    NA        5    65   
6 1430939 4943210    6    NA
```

I would like to calculate the maximum depth between the x/y values that are not NA and add this to a new column in the row of the starting x/y values. So max depth of rows 2-5. An example of the output desired.

```
    x       y       time depth newvar
1 1430934 4943206    1    NA     84
2    NA    NA        2    10     NA
3    NA    NA        3    19     NA
4    NA    NA        4    84     NA
5    NA    NA        5    65     NA
6 1430939 4943210    6    NA     NA
```

This is to repeat whenever a new x/y value is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `cumsum` with `!is.na` to get the groups for ave like:

```
data$newvar <- ave(data$depth, cumsum(!is.na(data$x)), FUN=
 function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else {
  c(max(x, na.rm=TRUE), rep(NA, length(x)-1))})
data
#        x       y time depth newvar
#1 1430934 4943206    1    NA     84
#2    <NA>    <NA>    2    10     NA
#3    <NA>    <NA>    3    19     NA
#4    <NA>    <NA>    4    84     NA
#5    <NA>    <NA>    5    65     NA
#6 1430939 4943210    6    NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `ave` like below

```
df <- within(df,
             newvar <- ave(depth,
                           ceiling(time/5),
                           FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x)>1&is.na(x),max(na.omit(x)),NA)))
```

such that

```
> df
        x       y time depth newvar
1 1430934 4943206    1    NA     84
2      NA      NA    2    10     NA
3      NA      NA    3    19     NA
4      NA      NA    4    84     NA
5      NA      NA    5    65     NA
6 1430939 4943210    6    NA     NA
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1430934L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1430939L), y = c(4943206L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4943210L), time = 1:6, depth = c(NA, 10L, 19L, 
84L, 65L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can create groups of every 5 rows and update the first row in group as `max` value in the group ignoring `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(time/5)) %>%
  mutate(depth = ifelse(row_number() == 1, max(depth, na.rm = TRUE), NA))
```

---

In base R, we can use `tapply` :

```
inds <- seq(1, nrow(df), 5)
df$depth[inds] <- tapply(df$depth, ceiling(df$time/5), max, na.rm = TRUE)
df$depth[-inds] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, newvar := replace(frollapply(depth, 5L, max, na.rm=TRUE, align="left"),
    seq(.N) %% 5L != 1L, NA_integer_)]
```